# Why does the NVL2 function don't accept LONG values in its second and third parameters?

Tags: database, oracle, nvl

The [official Oracle database documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm) says that the NVL2 function doesn't allow values of type LONG in its second and third parameters though it doesn't explain why.

Why do we have this restriction? Is there any specific reason for this restriction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming, it is a question of the rationale behind Oracle's product design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `LONG` columns are long, loooong (pun intended :)) deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore: [Oracle 9.0.1 -
 Deprecated and Desupported Features](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90120/ch4_dep.htm#6690)

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. Read about the Long data type and seems it's disallowed for a lot of operations as per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1831

Comment: Yup, it is, better not to use it if you don't have to!